# facebook ui send 500 error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-ui

When I call a facebook ui send dialog and share a url linking to my fb app (which requires fb login as age restricted) I get a 500 application error.

I have read a few SO posts about the issue and the error is due to fb not being able to read the url destination. Does anyone know a solution to this when the link is to a fb login required app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your content is age restricted, then it probably shouldn’t get shown to the user’s friends, cause *all* of them could see the snippet posted with the link.

Comment: but they wouldn't be able to access the app unless their facebook age was of the approved minimum. There is nothing shared (content wise) apart from the link.